# Can you have a dropdown list in Access without a form?

Tags: ms-access, drop-down-menu

I want to have a dropdown menu to enter data from a list directly into the Access table, ie into the cells for a particular column/field.

Can this be done or do you have to use a form?

If it can be done, how do you specify the options for the list?

Comment: Please read the following to know what you are getting into. [Look up Fields are evil](http://access.mvps.org/access/lookupfields.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Go to table design. At the bottom, select the second tab "Lookup" (or similar, it is localised) and specify the lookup values or source.

Comment: Thanks - can you explain in a bit more detail how I can use that to create a dropdown - using Access 2007-2010

Comment: Not really, I refrain from using the feature, but I binged for it and the first hit is [Create a lookup field](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-lookup-field-87E84CBD-D60C-4473-8A98-3E391C42F239)

Comment: Please read the following to know what you are getting into. [Look up Fields are evil.](http://access.mvps.org/access/lookupfields.htm)

Comment: Use a form. Your users should't ever directly interact with a table. 
And as already pointed out LookUp fields are the spawn of satan. Create another table and make a proper look up combo based on it.